# failed to create task or type checkenv Cause The name is undefined

Tags: android, ant, jenkins, cordova, jenkins-plugins

I know there are some questions related to this but what Im trying to do is a bit different.

my 2 targets that I have specified in my project config options are

clean
debug

both of them are available by default so I dont have to write new code for any additional targets. but my build is still failed.

```
Started by user anonymous
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jenkins-data/jobs/anttest1/workspace
Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/jenkins/jenkins-data/jobs/anttest1/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@4603278f
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision 17b9fd2ee52d01e7a425822f353222445e3a82c7 (EventMatrix_Cordova_App/HEAD, EventMatrix_Cordova_App/master)
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from EventMatrix_Cordova_App
Seen branch in repository EventMatrix_Cordova_App/HEAD
Seen branch in repository EventMatrix_Cordova_App/master
Commencing build of Revision 17b9fd2ee52d01e7a425822f353222445e3a82c7 (EventMatrix_Cordova_App/HEAD, EventMatrix_Cordova_App/master)
Checking out Revision 17b9fd2ee52d01e7a425822f353222445e3a82c7 (EventMatrix_Cordova_App/HEAD, EventMatrix_Cordova_App/master)
Warning : There are multiple branch changesets here
[mysteryshopper_version2] $ ant -file build.xml -Dlabel=anttest1-42 clean
Buildfile: /var/lib/jenkins/jenkins-data/jobs/anttest1/workspace/mysteryshopper_version2/build.xml
  **[taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource anttasks.properties. It could not be found.
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource emma_ant.properties. It could not be found.**

-**check-env**:

BUILD FAILED
/usr/local/lib/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:392: Problem: **failed to create task or type checkenv**
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.


Total time: 0 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

can someone  help me on this  ??

Comment: Your ANT installation on Jenkins cannot find the 3rd party android jar containing the checkenv task. See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/ant-tasks

Comment: the results that you can see are from jenkins that is installed on my company's server. I tried the same thing on my own computer and it perfectly worked fine. just a quick  question, Is this 3rd party android jar file inside the android-sdk-linux folder ? because I think its a permission or read issue. I had the same issue with the android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml file. I fixed it by allowing the other user to read/write and execute.

Comment: If I allow other users(in my case jenkins) the read/write and execute permission to android-sdk-linux folder and all its sub directories, will that be a problem ? because my senior "does not want to open that folder to the world" .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<checkenv />` is required for the Android build, it's in a library in the Android SDK directory.  I had the same problem and discovered the cause was a bad directory in the `local.properties` file required by `build.xml` and `buildAndroid.xml`.  Here's a sample of my `local.properties` file:

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.

# location of the SDK. This is only used by Ant
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
sdk.dir=/Users/myusername/android-sdk-macosx
```

This gets generated automatically when I'm in Eclipse, but when Eclipse is closed and I'm working with ant at the command line, it was not updated and had some other user's information that had been committed to SVN and I checked out with an svn update.

I updated it to point to my own Android SDK directory and everything started working.

Hope that helps!

Comment: still the same. can you check the permissions on yyour android-sdk-macosx folder and tell me I guess I have a write issue

Comment: permissions on that folder are drwxr-x---@

Comment: Also, make sure you are using Apache ant 1.8.x.

Comment: org.jenkins-ci.plugins:ant:1.2

Comment: there is no option to upgrade to 1.8.x

Comment: Can you try it using a newer version of Ant?  Or are you forced to use this version because of the jenkins requirement?

Comment: I did the same thing on my own computer it worked perfectly fine but when I run it on jenkins on my company's server it fails. the only difference that i can see is that on my computer I have /home/tanzeelrana/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/anttasks.jar whereas on my company's server this file has a ame ant-tasks.jar

Comment: If you go to jenkins website they say that the latest release is 1.2 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Ant+Plugin

how are you using the 1.8.x version of ant on your computer?

Comment: I would set the directory in local.properties to point to the AndroidSDK directory on the server.  I am not familiar with Jenkins, unfortunately, so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it from that side.

Comment: I set the dir in local.properties to point to my AndroidSDK dir and now Im using 1.8.2 ant but the problem still remains the same. the permissions on the sdk folder are as follo :

 drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4096 Jun 10 12:46 android-sdk-linux

Comment: @tanzeelrana this answer is not solve problem for me,. :-(,. i had  same error which you face. give a solution. i set the sdk.dir=E:\\JEGADEES\\Android\\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030 path in my local.properties file also.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with `anttasks.properties` or `emma_ant.properties`(at least for me). I fixed it differently. My target `build.xml` had these lines

```
<property file="local.properties"/>
<property file="project.properties"/>
<property file="ant.properties"/>
```

Curiously enough, the `local.properties` was missing from the `build.xml` folder, whereas the other two were present. Luckily, I had already had it because of my previous attempt with Android Studio i.e. in `StudioProjects/<my project>/local.properties`. In other words it is automatically created by Android Studio. If you don't have it, this is its content:

```
## This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
#Fri Apr 22 21:28:15 EEST 2016
ndk.dir=home/<user>/android-ndk-r11c
sdk.dir=home/<user>/Android/Sdk
```

So, you basically can create it yourself specifying the paths of your SDK and possibly NDK.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had an antbuild running while updating the build tools resulting in a file access conflict :) SDK Manager showed it as installed though. Deleting and re-installing fixed the problem.