# Building error in hello world app of konyone studio

Tags: android, ant, adt, temenos-quantum

I'm trying to build a small helloworld form from the konyone studio, while building the app am getting the error as :

```
    compile:
     [echo] Packaging the android Helloworld application
     [exec] Buildfile: C:\workspace\temp\Helloworld\build\luaandroid\dist\Helloworld\build.xml
     [exec]   [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource anttasks.properties. It could not be found.
     [exec] 
     [exec] -set-mode-check:
     [exec] 
     [exec] -set-debug-files:
     [exec] 
     [exec] -check-env:
     [exec] 
     [exec] BUILD FAILED
     [exec] C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:401: Problem: failed to create task or type checkenv
     [exec] Cause: The name is undefined.
     [exec] Action: Check the spelling.
     [exec] Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
     [exec] Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
     [exec] 
     [exec] 
     [exec] Total time: 2 seconds
[11-10-2013 01:39:42]Ant build error=exec returned: 1
[11-10-2013 01:39:42]Build Generation failed for platform Android.
[11-10-2013 01:39:42]Total time taken: 15390 ms
[11-10-2013 01:39:42]Build Generation has failed for the following platforms:-->Android
[11-10-2013 01:39:42]<-----------Build Generation job is completed--------------->
```

can someone tell me how to get rid of this problem.
Any one there to solve this issue...??

Comment: possible duplicate of [failed to create task or type checkenv Cause The name is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074286/failed-to-create-task-or-type-checkenv-cause-the-name-is-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

This does sound like an Ant issue, rather than a Kony issue.  Check that you have followed the installation / configuration instructions in the Kony documentation here: http://developer.kony.com/twiki/pub/Portal/Docs/Kony_Studio_InstallationGuide/Default.htm#Android.htm

Answer (score 0):

go and check in windows->preference->then choose kony studio->check build option

or else follow the kony help in kony studio
[hello world getting start](http://docs.kony.com/video_tutorials/default.htm#Getting_Started.htm?TocPath=_____1)

Answer (score 0):

```
JAVA_HOME  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_38
ANT_HOME   D:\apache-ant-1.9.3
PATH       D:\sdk\tools;D:\sdk\platform-tools;D:\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Kony\ImageMagick;
```

You need to set a path in your Environment variables,Without these things you can't able to do Build generation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give ANT_HOME path in your environment variables.

[use this link download Apache ant](https://ant.apache.org/antnews.html)